# Adding Listview Row Items to the database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

This code is working if my listview has only 1 row. But if the listview has two or more rows, it double~triple etc.

```
foreach(ListViewItem ItemRow in this.listViewPOS.Items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listViewPOS.Count; i++)
    {
        SQLConn.sqL = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails(ProductID, OrderID, SRP, Quantity, Discount, Total) VALUES('" + ItemRow.SubItems[0].Text + "'," +
                "'" + OrderID + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[3].Text + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[4].Text + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[5].Text + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[6].Text + "')";

        SQLConn.ConnDB();
        SQLConn.cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLConn.sqL, SQLConn.conn);
        SQLConn.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: alright, i will change it.. thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looping the item list two times one using foreach and the second using  for loop use either one

eg

```
foreach(ListViewItem ItemRow in this.listViewPOS.Items)
{
            SQLConn.sqL = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails(ProductID, OrderID, SRP, Quantity, Discount, Total) VALUES('" + ItemRow.SubItems[0].Text + "'," +
                "'" + OrderID + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[3].Text + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[4].Text + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[5].Text + "', '" + ItemRow.SubItems[6].Text + "')";

        SQLConn.ConnDB();
        SQLConn.cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLConn.sqL, SQLConn.conn);
        SQLConn.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

Comment: Use a parametric query to prevent a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @RezaAghaei .. great advice..I skipped it as Little Bobby Tables – marc_s already advised it in command. and I don't want the  beginner to get confused trying something new in mid of this issue